# Android - local and remote model structure

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I wonder if my approach is correct and if not - then what is the most common way to achieve this..

My remote db is Firebase Firestore

My local db is Room

Example entity is User and I have it as 3 variants:

- UserEntity: represents Room table
- UserModel: represents Firestore
- User: for usage across the viewmodels (contains the actual data I want to show in app)

Now the part I doubt is the parsing:

Entity must have:

- toModel when I want to sync the local with remote
- toUser because that is the source of data I user primarily

Model must have:

- toEntity when I want to store the remote data to local

User must have:

- toEntity when I want to update local db
- toModel when I want to update remote db

I this how its supposed to be :)? My models are not that complex right now but they could expand in the future.